# Ajax form after submit collapse div and change image from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So, I have a form with a background image (envelope). After submit I want to stay on the same page and collapse part of the div that contains the  form and show only a image with thank you bla bla. How to do this smooth collapse and replacement? If anyone has some ideas or links, I would be grateful.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#form1").submit(function(){
            $("#formplic").html("<img src='images/thanks.png'/>");
        });
    }); 
</script> 

<div id="formplic"><img src="images/form.png"/></div>

<form id="form1" action="send.php" onSubmit="return chkForm(this)" name="form1" method="post" >
    <textarea name="message" cols="4" rows="4"  id="message" value=""></textarea>
    <input type="text"  id="name" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="text"  id="email" name="email" value="" />    
    <input type="submit" value="" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement the Ajax submit, or just about the collapsing animation? Either way, take a few minutes to read through [this list of jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/) and I'm sure you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about some fading stuff ?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#form1").submit(function(){
        $("#formplic").fadeOut(1000, function() {
             $(this).html("<img src='images/thanks.png'/>").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

or sliding stuff ?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#form1").submit(function(){
        $("#formplic").slideUp(1000, function() {
             $(this).html("<img src='images/thanks.png'/>").slideDown(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

This sort of thing should be pretty straight forward with a little searching !

Comment: It's impossible to send the form the regular way without either refreshing or leaving the page. However you could prevent the form from submitting and do the submitting with ajax to avoid a reload.